# Casting a struct member between uint8_t and char, with regard to serial transfer

Tags: serial, c++, uart, pointer, struct

Im simply trying to pass my payload to another device that has the same architecture and struct. I'm using UART to transfer, and modeling the protocol from EasyTransfer.

When I call `Serial.print((char*)mydata.data);` in Transfer it prints Hello World as expected.

Calling that same line in Receive prints a '?' to console. This may be some background behavior with Arduino, or I'm just not casting/handling the pointers correctly. How can I get this print out to function properly?

Transfer Sketch

```
#include <EasyTransfer.h>

//create object
EasyTransfer TransferObject; 

//Struct contents must be idential to struct from other board
#define PAYLOAD_SIZE 255
struct SEND_DATA_STRUCTURE
{
  int blinks;
  int pause;

  uint8_t data[PAYLOAD_SIZE];
};

//give a name to the group of data
SEND_DATA_STRUCTURE mydata;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //#define details(name) (byte*)&name,sizeof(name) 
  TransferObject.begin(details(mydata), &Serial);
  
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  //initalize not so random number generator
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));
  
}
 
void loop()
{
  //mydata.blinks = random(5);
  //mydata.pause = random(5);

  //Create payload to transfer
  char* payload = "Hello World!";

  //Fill array with data
  strncpy((char *)mydata.data, payload, PAYLOAD_SIZE);

  //Print sample
  Serial.print((char*)mydata.data);
  
  //send the entire struct
  TransferObject.sendData();
  
  delay(5000);
}
```

Receive Sketch

```
    #include <EasyTransfer.h>

//create object
EasyTransfer TransferObject; 

//Struct contents must be idential to struct from other board
#define PAYLOAD_SIZE 255
struct RECEIVE_DATA_STRUCTURE
{
  int blinks;
  int pause;
  
  uint8_t data[PAYLOAD_SIZE];
};

//give a name to the group of data
RECEIVE_DATA_STRUCTURE mydata;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //#define details(name) (byte*)&name,sizeof(name) 
  TransferObject.begin(details(mydata), &Serial);
  
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  
}

void loop()
{
  //check and see if a data packet has come in. 
  if(TransferObject.receiveData())
  {
    Serial.print("active");
    //print data payload
    Serial.print((char*)mydata.data);
    }
  
  //you should make this delay shorter then your transmit delay or else messages could be lost
  delay(250);
```

This is [an exerpt and variant from this library](https://github.com/madsci1016/Arduino-EasyTransfer/tree/master/EasyTransfer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually falling into a common problem with pointers in structs.

This structure:

```
struct SEND_DATA_STRUCTURE
{
  int blinks;
  int pause;

  uint8_t *data;
};
```

contains three values: blinks, pause and a pointer to the data.

```
uint8_t *data;
```

That doesn't contain the data. That only contains the address that the data is stored at in memory.  When you transfer the struct it's that address that you are sending - then when the other end tries to print it all it can do is look at the address it's been told about and try and print whatever is in there - and that is complete garbage.

Instead of storing a pointer to the data you need to store the actual data itself. That means that you need to decide upon a maximum size for that data and pre-allocate the memory within the struct:

```
#define DATA_SIZE 40

struct SEND_DATA_STRUCTURE
{
  int blinks;
  int pause;

  uint8_t data[DATA_SIZE];
};
```

Now in order to get the data into that struct you need to fill that array with your payload. For strings the simplest way is:

```
strncpy((char *)mydata.data, payload, DATA_SIZE);
```

That will copy *up to* `DATA_SIZE` characters from `payload` into `mydata.data`.

Note that if `payload` contains more than `DATA_SIZE-1` characters the data in `mydata.data` will not be NULL terminated. You can get round that by forcing NULL termination:

```
mydata.data[DATA_SIZE-1] = 0;
```

---

In your revised code your payload size is too big. The way the EasyTransfer library works is it has a single byte for the size of the payload. Your total payload size is PAYLOAD_SIZE + 2 ints - that is 255 + 2 + 2 = 259 bytes.  Placed into a single byte that gets truncated to 3. That means you are actually transferring one and a half integers and nothing else.

You need to ensure that your entire struct never exceeds 255 bytes. So you can have a maximum size of data, once you have taken your two integers into account (assuming 16-bit integers on an 8-bit Arduino), of 251 bytes.

Comment: Thanks Majenko! And how might I read the data post transfer? Serial.print((char*)mydata.data); shows no output on the recieving device

Comment: Did you replicate the same struct on the receiving end?

Comment: They appear to be the same, yeah. I can update that original post with my new code, if that helps.

Comment: Yes. Please do.

Comment: Okay, done. :-)

Comment: See my note at the end of my now modified answer.

Comment: I COMPLETELY overlooked that, thank you so much.