# Sending GPS data between two Arduinos using Easy Transfer

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, softwareserial, communication, gps

I'm trying to get GPS data transmitted from one Arduino UNO to a second unit to eventually be displayed on an LCD and stored in an SD card.  I am using Xbees S2C's on Xbee Shield's to do this.  The GPS information is coming from an Adafruit ultimate GPS breakout.

First I wanted so send two NMEA sentences as strings, but have since found that the EasyTransfer library does not like that.  I was getting information but it was just random characters, sort of.  The pattern was repeated, so it was consistent.

After doing some searching I thought the best way to do it was to convert my strings to character arrays and send those.  I managed to successfully convert them to character arrays, but I can't seem to get them over to the other Arduino.  I do get the FIX int as well as the Length int that I sent over just to make sure it is working.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Sender code:

```cpp
#include <EasyTransfer.h>
#include <Adafruit_GPS.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 

SoftwareSerial mySerial(3, 2); //Initialize SoftwareSerial, and tell it you will be connecting through pins 2 and 3
Adafruit_GPS GPS(&mySerial); //Create GPS object

String NMEA1;  //We will use this variable to hold our first NMEA sentence
String NMEA2;  //We will use this variable to hold our second NMEA sentence
char c;       //Used to read the characters spewing from the GPS module
int fix = 0;
long GPStime = 0;
int val = 0;

EasyTransfer ET;

//Declare Data Structure for the EasyTransfer Library
//Note: Data Structure must be same on TX and RX...

struct DATA_STRUCTURE{
 int fixed;
 int length1;
 int length2;
 char* nmea1;
 char* nmea2;
};

DATA_STRUCTURE myData;

void setup()
{
  //Initalizing EasyTransfer Serial Ports
  Serial.begin(115200);
  ET.begin(details(myData), &Serial);
  GPS.begin(9600);       //Turn GPS on at baud rate of 9600
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  //Serial.println("Two GPS Sentences From GPS");
  GPS.sendCommand("$PGCMD,33,0*6D"); // Turn Off GPS Antenna Update
  GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCGGA); //Tell GPS we want only $GPRMC and $GPGGA NMEA sentences
  GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_UPDATE_10HZ);   // 10 Hz update rate
  delay(1000);  //Pause
}

void loop()
{
  readGPS();  //This is a function we define below which reads two NMEA sentences from GPS
  //Sending Data
  ET.sendData();
}

void readGPS()    //This function will read and remember two NMEA sentences from GPS
{  
  clearGPS();    //Serial port probably has old or corrupt data, so begin by clearing it all out
  while(!GPS.newNMEAreceived())   //Keep reading characters in this loop until a good NMEA sentence is received
  { 
    c=GPS.read(); //read a character from the GPS
  }
  GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA());  //Once you get a good NMEA, parse it
  NMEA1=GPS.lastNMEA();      //Once parsed, save NMEA sentence into NMEA1
  while(!GPS.newNMEAreceived()) //Go out and get the second NMEA sentence, should be different type than the first one read above.
  { 
    c=GPS.read();
  }
  GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA());
  NMEA2=GPS.lastNMEA();

  fix = GPS.fix;
  if (fix == 1)
  {
    //Serial.print("FIXED");
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    //Serial.print(NMEA1);
    myData.fixed = 1;
    int str_len1 = NMEA1.length();
    char char_array1[str_len1];
    NMEA1.toCharArray(char_array1, str_len1);
    myData.length1 = str_len1;

    //Serial.print(char_array1);
    //Serial.println("");
    //Serial.println("");
    myData.nmea1 = char_array1;

  }
  else
  {
    //Serial.println("No fix");
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    myData.fixed = 0;

  }
}

void clearGPS() //Since between GPS reads, we still have data streaming in, we need to clear the old data by reading a few sentences, and discarding these
{  
  while(!GPS.newNMEAreceived()) 
  {
    c=GPS.read();
  }
  GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA());
  while(!GPS.newNMEAreceived()) 
  {
    c=GPS.read();
  }
  GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA());
}
```

Receiver Code:

```cpp
#include <EasyTransfer.h>
#include "Wire.h"
#include "Adafruit_LiquidCrystal.h"

EasyTransfer ET;

Adafruit_LiquidCrystal lcd(0);

//Declare Data Structure for the EasyTransfer Library
//Note: Data Structure must be same on TX and RX...

struct DATA_STRUCTURE{
 int fixed;
 int length1;
 int length2;
 char* nmea1;
 char* nmea2;
 //int pause;
};

DATA_STRUCTURE myData;

char* NMEA1[100] = {0};

void setup()
{
 //Initalizing EasyTransfer Serial Ports
 Serial.begin(115200);
 ET.begin(details(myData), &Serial);

 lcd.begin(20, 4);
 lcd.clear();
 lcd.setBacklight(HIGH);

 pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(13, LOW);


}

void loop()
{
  //check and see if a data packet has come in. 
  if(ET.receiveData()){
    //this is how you access the variables. [name of the group].[variable name]
    int FIX = myData.fixed;
    int LENGTH1 = myData.length1;
    char* NMEA1 = myData.nmea1;
    Serial.println(FIX);
    Serial.println(LENGTH1);
    Serial.print(NMEA1);
    Serial.println("");
    if (myData.fixed == 1)
    {
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      lcd.setCursor(10, 3);
      lcd.print(" GPS Fixed");
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      lcd.setCursor(10, 3);
      lcd.print("No GPS Fix");
    }
  }

  delay(1000);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!
K-Bert

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting a struct member between uint8\_t and char, with regard to serial transfer](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/22428/casting-a-struct-member-between-uint8-t-and-char-with-regard-to-serial-transfer)